# How to know when client disconnects in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, connection, long-polling

I'm trying to use HTTP long polling, roughly something like this:

```
@app.route('/get_stuff', methods=["GET"])
def get_stuff():
    while True:
        stuff = database.lookupSomething()
        if stuff:
            return json.dumps(stuff)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
```

This works excellent however if the client cuts the connection, the server will still run the loop. I would like to replace the loop with something like this:

```
while client.is_connected():
    ....
```

However, I cannot find any way of knowing if the connection is still valid. Others have asked the same question, and the answer has been to use SocketIO. I cannot do this however and would rather use a simple GET request like above. Is there a way of knowing if the client has closed his connection?

Comment: Using the definitions in [RFC6202](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6202), your code implements "HTTP Streaming", not "HTTP Long Polling".

Comment: Streaming: "The HTTP streaming mechanism keeps a request open indefinitely.  It never terminates the request or closes the connection, even after the server pushes data to the client."

Comment: Long polling: "The server achieves these efficiencies by responding to a request only when a particular event, status, or timeout has occurred.".

Comment: I don't keep the connection indefinitely, streaming objects continuously. I send one response but not until the object is there to be sent. Thus, long polling.

Comment: You are right, I am wrong. I was confused by your `while True` loop. I missed the "return", and thought you were sending back a series of JSON documents, not just one.